# ConvertFrom-Json Loop Through Object

Tags: json, loops, powershell

I am pretty new to PowerShell and have the following code:

```
$jsonResponse = @"
{
"departments":[{"id":81,"department":"Sales"},{"id":61,"department":"IT Support"}]
}
"@

$myCustomObject = $jsonResponse | ConvertFrom-Json

$myCustomObject.departments.department[0]
$myCustomObject.departments.department[1]
```

Which allows me to access elements of the customObject (converted from JSON).

What I need is the ability to loop through the object so I can access each element i.e.

```
object_loop
{
 $myCustomObject.departments.department[x]
}
```

where x is the loop increment.

Sorry of this is silly question but I have googled and can't find a simple example.

Cheers for any help.

Duncs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is as trivial as

```
foreach($obj in $myCustomObject.departments)
{
    Write-Host ("Got" + $obj.department)
}
```

Comment: wow. Cheers for the very simple explanation. I feel a bit silly for asking now :). Works like a charm. Duncs